# Behavior while using $ne for nested documents inside mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a document like the one mentioned below.

```
db.students.insertMany([
  { id: 1, name: 'Ryan', gender: 'M', data: [{a: 1, b: 2}]},
  { id: 2, name: 'Joanna', gender: 'F', data: [{a: 1, b: 3}]},
  { id: 3, name: 'Joanna', gender: 'M', data: [{a: 3, b: 4}]},
  { id: 4, name: 'Joanna', gender: 'F', data: [{a: 1, b: 2}]},
  { id: 5, name: 'Joanna', gender: 'M', data: [{a: 5, b: 6}]}
]);
```

How do I get the document excluding a:1 and b:2, i.e the returned documents should not contain either of those two values for an and b. Using the below query does not yield the result and omits the 2nd document i.e the document with id = 2

`{ id: 2, name: 'Joanna', gender: 'F', data: [{a: 1, b: 3}]}`

```
db.students.find({"data.a": {$ne: 1}, "data.b": {$ne: 2}});
```

yields

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6409b9f5da111ab92c86ef10"), "id" : 3, "name" : "Joanna", "gender" : "M", "data" : [ { "a" : 3, "b" : 4 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6409b9f5da111ab92c86ef12"), "id" : 5, "name" : "Joanna", "gender" : "M", "data" : [ { "a" : 5, "b" : 6 } ] }
```

How do I get the desired result with the 2nd document? Also how does the above query work?

Answer (score 0):

you almost get there. you just need to put the query inside operator `$or`,  [operator query $or](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

that would be like:

```
db.students.find({
  "$or": [
    {
      "data.a": { "$ne": 1 }
    },
    {
      "data.b": { "$ne": 2 }
    }
  ]
})
```

try on [MONGO-PLAYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gNF7O1vGHAQ)

Comment: Hey Tobok, it still gives me the same result, does not give me the document with id: 2

Comment: i just tried it, the ouput is same as your expectation

Comment: @SangeethK i did a bit change before, you may wanna try it again.

Comment: Sorry, I still see the same output with just 2 documents instead of 3. This is in the link that you shared in your answer.

Comment: my bad, you mention about `excluding a:1 and b:2`. if you want 3 result, just replace `$and` to `$or`. actually i used `$or` before  [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75684524/timeline#history_1e1ea77b-d064-4085-a382-2b5b8989bdee)